# How to Add two time fields to equal an integer in an SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedures, time, int

**EDIT 1**

I am inserting into a table using a stored procedure, and one of my columns is an `int` data-type. What is going to be input and calculated into that cell, is the sum of dividing two times with data-type `time(0)`. I simply have two times as such:

07:30:00

06:45:53

I then divide the biggest from the smallest and then round it up to the biggest whole number.

6:45:53 / 7:30:00 = 1 (Rounded).

On Excel this works, and I expect it converts 7:30:00 into 7.5 for example.

Yet in SQL, I can't type in a time without using quotation and therefore won't let me sum them using the `SUM()` method.

My SQL stored Procedure (My attempt):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable_1
Values(REPLACE(NEWID(),'-',''),@pName,@pDate,SUM('07:30:00'/@pLoggedInTime),@pCallsIn,@pCallsOut,@pLoggedInTime,@pTalkTime,@pHoldTime)
```

I don't know if this is also another problem, but one of the times that I am using in the sum is from a parameter.

**Is there a way to `SUM()` two time fields to result in an integer value on SQL, much like what happens on Excel? And if so, how?**

Comment: I'm unclear from your description what the expected result is from adding `07:30:00` and `06:45:53`. But please note that the SQL Server `time` data type is, specifically, for storing a *time of day*, not a *time interval*. As such, it doesn't support (because it doesn't make sense) directly adding two values of this type together.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for your comment. Basically, An example would be, 7:30:00 / 6:45:53 = 1 (Rounded). In Excel, if you type those two values in and divide them using the SUM() function, it somehow converts them into a number. It is like it is turning 7:30:00 into 7.5.  I wondered if this is possible on SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
     TimeCol1 TIME(0)
    ,Timecol2 TIME(0))

INSERT INTO #Test (TimeCol1, TimeCol2) VALUES ('07:30:00', '06:45:53')
INSERT INTO #Test (TimeCol1, TimeCol2) VALUES ('06:45:53','07:30:00')

select *, CONVERT(time, CONVERT(datetime, TimeCol2) + CONVERT(datetime, TimeCol1))  FROM #Test
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, this is not what I intend to do. Perhaps I made my question a bit unclear, I'll edit the question with an example, but you may also want to read my comment back to Damien.